# How to share mouse and keyboard via Wi-Fi to Android?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, android

I use [1keyboard](https://itunes.apple.com/app/1keyboard/id766939888) via Bluetooth to share keyboard with my Android phones, but this is less productive than [Logitech's Flow](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options/page/flow-multi-device-control) where I can switch between devices much faster and more seamlessly.

Is there an app that can help me sharing keyboard and mouse with Android phones?

Answer (score 1):

The webpage at [alternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/software/1keyboard/?platform=mac) lists some alternatives to 1keyboard for macOS.

Comment: Hi, I am not looking for alternatives to 1keyboard. I am looking for alternatives to Flow.

Comment: @aeroxy See if this helps: https://alternativeto.net/software/logitech-options/

Comment: Synergy doesn't work on Android and the other apps doesn't share keyboard.